# Keep data after page refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, refresh

I have a small webpage app that calculates distance and time based on the users inputs. It works fine, however, my mobile browser (Chrome) insists on refreshing my tab after closing chrome for about 15 mins. All page data is lost when this happens so the user no longer has the important info/data. Is there any way around this? Here is my code

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {

function converToMinutes(s) {
    var c = s.split(':');
    return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

function parseTime(s) {
    var seconds = parseInt(s) % 60;
    return Math.floor(parseInt(s) / 60) + ":" + ((seconds < 10)?"0"+seconds:seconds);
}


var endTime = document.getElementById("etime").value; 
var startTime = converToMinutes(document.getElementById("stime").value);
var converted = parseTime(startTime - endTime);


document.getElementById('finishtime').innerHTML = "You will finish your break at " + converted;

}
```

HTML

```
<p>Please enter minutes</p>
<input type="text" id="etime">
<br>
<p>Please enter time in 24 hour format (eg. 15:00)</p>
<input type="text" id="stime">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="finishtime">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in HTML5 Web storage, just include below code in your JS code

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
localStorage.setItem("convertedTime", converted);
} else {
// Sorry! No Web Storage support
}
```

And whenever you want to fetch those stored data, you can get it just as below

```
var convertedTime=localStorage.getItem("convertedTime");
```

And then you can use it anywhere you want after reloading the page.

Comment: is there any way I can load the stored date in my input

Answer (score -1):

You can use clientside storage  techniques like localstorage to implement this.
Localstorage allows you to store domain specific key value pair data offlie.Although you can serialize objects and place them as string for a particular key. You can even you IndexDB. Client side database similar to sql.
Using any of these you can make sure that no data is lost. Until the y clear them or you clear them.

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key,value) -> will set a key value pair
window.localStorage.getItem(key,value) -> will get a key value pair
```

For more

[HTML 5 rocks client side storage](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/)

[visit here for indexdb Html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/websql-indexeddb/)